# перестал загружаться MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint, mysql-workbench

На linux mint 18.3 установлен MySQL Workbench, все работало нормально, но внезапно перестал загружаться. При открытии мигает окно и сразу пропадает, исчезает вниз экрана. Как это исправить?

При запуске приложения (intellij idea, java), использующего базы данных, ошибок не вылетает, приложение работает, т.е. связь с базой данной сохранилась

При запуске из консоли ошибка:

```
*** Error in `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000033b3ba0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fc1aae8f7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fc1aae9837a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fc1aae9c53c]
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.6.3.6(_ZN16DocumentsSection6layoutEP6_cairo+0x567)[0x7fc1b0d0ce17]
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.6.3.6(_ZN16DocumentsSection7repaintEP6_cairoiiii+0x89)[0x7fc1b0d0cfd9]
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libmforms.so.6.3.6(_ZN6mforms3gtk11DrawBoxImpl7repaintEP15_GdkEventExposePNS_7DrawBoxE+0x10d)[0x7fc1ac29985d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1(+0x2ef21b)[0x7fc1ad0ed21b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x132aec)[0x7fc1ade69aec]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x145)[0x7fc1aeb5efa5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x22264)[0x7fc1aeb71264]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xa59)[0x7fc1aeb797f9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x8f)[0x7fc1aeb7a08f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x24a93c)[0x7fc1adf8193c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main_do_event+0x532)[0x7fc1ade688a2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x41b9f)[0x7fc1ae3c3b9f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x41b45)[0x7fc1ae3c3b45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x3e671)[0x7fc1ae3c0671]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(gdk_window_process_all_updates+0x118)[0x7fc1ae3c0fa8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0xb6971)[0x7fc1added971]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x1dd57)[0x7fc1ae39fd57]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x15a)[0x7fc1aedec04a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4a3f0)[0x7fc1aedec3f0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0xc2)[0x7fc1aedec712]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xb7)[0x7fc1ade67697]
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin(main+0x3be)[0x4be62e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fc1aae38830]
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin(_start+0x29)[0x4c0449]

======= Memory map: ========
00400000-005bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8270806                            /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
007bf000-007e2000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 8270806                            /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
007e2000-007e5000 rw-p 001e2000 08:01 8270806                            /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
```

Comment: Запустите из консоли и посмотрите с какой ошибкой вылетает. Возможно было обновление и WB хочет старые библиотеки.

Comment: `для запуска достаточно удалить ~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml` так пишут в интернетах.